# How to display Active Storage attached file when editing form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am building an Agreement management app. Each Agreement has vendor, activation, expiration dates and file. File is an attached agreement in pdf. I use Active Storage for attaching files. When I edit the form I don't see the attached file. As a consequence if I change any other parameter let's say vendor and update Agreement the previously attached file is being deleted.

[Editing Agreement form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiETL.png)

What should I do to get the attached file name to be present on update and not being removed if I don't upload any other file while editing?

Update:

Here is the code. I have not done any adjustments to the generated agreements_controller.rb except for adding :file to permitted params.

```
agreement.rb

class Agreement < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :vendor
  has_one_attached :file  
end


agreements_controller.rb

class AgreementsController < ApplicationController
  def agreement_params
    params.require(:agreement).permit(:vendor_id, :activation_date, :expiration_date, :file)
  end
end


_form.html.erb

<%= form_with(model: agreement, local: true) do |form| %>
…
<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :file %>
    <%= form.file_field :file %>
 </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you show us some code please

Comment: The problem is not that the file is not shown, the problem is that you are updating the attachment even when the parameter is empty. You have to show some code (edit and update action, edit form at least)

Comment: Thanking to your explanation I figured out I have to check in agreements_controller.rb if agreement_params contain new attached file on update. And if it does not I should use previously attached file. I have added that line to the update function:
agreement_params[:file] = @agreement.file unless @agreement.file.attached?

I still don't see the previously attached file name while editing but at least it's not being delete if I don't upload new file

Answer (score 0):

Add in the Agreement  model

```
attribute :remove_file, :boolean,  default: false
after_save :purge_file, if: :remove_file
```